# More on the 'honorificabilitudinitatibus' citation

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, scansion, transcription

An early dictionary fits the longest word in Latin into a hexameter. In [a previous question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/7569/79) Expedito Bipes introduced this astonishing dictionary entry (1286), (and then later gave an alternative reading *"fuget"* for *fulget,* and another [useful link](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=U0KqGeTRAxUC&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=%22Fuget%20honorificabilitudinitatibus%22&source=bl&ots=l9rJI3TAGA&sig=Va6OrIB5AjXX0REJdVbaeHLM_Mo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRioessejeAhXHIpAKHSOCDPsQ6AEwBXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Fuget%20honorificabilitudinitatibus%22&f=false) )
 [image: a scanned dictionary entry]

And when it says (line3) 'in this verse,' it quotes two dactylic hexameters:

> *'Fulget hon/orifi-/cabili-/tudini-/tatibus/ iste
>
>   Et corri-/pit pen-/ultimam / honori-/fico /eas.'*

Have I transcribed and scanned it right? Have I missed two elisioins *penultim[am] honorific[e] eas*?  And what does it mean?

'That man sheds light upon acts of Honour;
 And hastens the end of (corripio) those acts(eas) /last but one/ ?*honorifice* honourably / ?*honorificitas* his respect hastens their demise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a supplement to the above answer, here is a full transcription and translation of the dictionary entry:

> Haec **honorificabilitas -tatis**, et haec **honorificabilitudinitas -tatis**:
>
> Et haec est longissima dictio, ut patet scilicet in hoc versu:
>
> > fulget honorificabilitudinitatibus iste
>
> Et corripit penultimam "honorifico" -tas.

Translation:

> **honorificabilitas -tatis** (f.), and **honorificabilitudinitas -tatis** (f.):
>
> This is the longest word, as is evident e.g. in the following verse:
>
> > He shines with "honorificabilitudinities"
>
> And the "-tas" shortens the penultimate syllable of "honorifico."

So, the last line is not a verse, but just an indication about the length of the vowels of this word. For this meaning of *corripio*, see I.B.4 of [the entry in L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcorripio). I'm not sure what it means, though, since the penultimate would normally be short anyway.

As another note, I believe the beginning "haec" is just a way to indicate the feminine gender of the noun.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is only one hexameter verse:

> Fulget hon/orifi/cabili/tudini/tatibus / iste.

This contains a word even longer than the headword.
It would not scan right without the addition of the dactylic *-tudini-*.
I would translate it as "he shines in his honor(-related thing)".

The following line does not seem to scan as a hexameter or pentameter, whether one elides or not.
The previous line was introduced as *in hoc versu*, not *in his versibus*, which further supports the conclusion.
The last line could be a comment on the hexameter.